# AJAX throws 403 for everyone but me

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(".divClass").click(function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                  content: this,
                  url: 'https://www.myurl.com',
                  success: function(data){
                    if(data == "API_OK"){
/* do stuff */
                    }
```

It throws 403 for everyone but me, no IP whitelisting or anything else.

Comment: what does your network say in detail?

Comment: where is https://www.myurl.com hosted?

Comment: Does it still do this from another network, on the same machine? Have you made any modifications to your host file on that system that would route things differently for you? Maybe a couple things to check...but the guy above is right, more network info would be helpful.

Comment: Works for me on any machine, but no one else.

Comment: Also any network.